# Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit'

Tags: tridion

I've installed the server hotfix rollup for SP1, and now get the .NET error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit'
```

when trying to access the Content Manager.  Does anyone know the root cause of this error in relation to the hotfix rollup?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the WebUI was in a separate place to the Tridion core install!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that and how you managed to solve the problem. Just to be certain: you fixed it by re-installing SP1 HR1 into the same location where Tridion is?